# How can I make a wall collapse from the top?

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation

I have a wall made up of many cubes and I would like to make it collapse starting from the top, row by row, kind of like a domino effect. I am pretty new to Blender physics and just can't figure out how to do it. I played around with rigid body simulation and force field settings, but it always starts collapsing from the centre, or the top row collapses but the next row don't follow it, etc. Using rigid body constraits is an option I guess, but it would be very tedious to set that up with hundreds of cubes.

Comment: Just to understand the situation: in your animation what is causing the wall to collapse?

Comment: That is basically irrelevant, if an object is used to make it collapse I will not render that object anyway. I only need a video with a wall collapsing from its top. I tried to use a sphere like a wrecking ball, but that made the cubes fall too randomly.

Comment: Do you have any animation/video reference of what you are trying to achive? Can you show the animation your not satisfied with and point out the problematic aspects?